# List of months from django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

This is the model:

```
class PaymentChart(models.Model):
    pharma = models.ForeignKey(PharmacyProfile , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wholesale = models.ForeignKey(WholesaleProfile , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reqeuest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    credit = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

I want to filter the list of all months, .ie

[09/2021,10/2021,11/2021]

Comment: Can you give an example of month filter?

Comment: Do you want a queryset of all months or also year as you describe the output in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `annotate`, `distinct`, `values_list` and `TruncMonth` so:

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

all_months = PaymentChart.objects.filter(paid=True).annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).distinct('month').values_list('month', flat=True)
```

[Source from Django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)